# Unterminated string constant with \\\ as value for replacement

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following code below doing some replacements.  It doesn't like the replace with `\\\`.  Error thrown is `Unterminated string constant`.   What is proper way to fix this so it doesn't throw error

```
function matchLiteral(_ctx: InternalContext, descriptor: TokenDescriptor) {
const phrasePattern =
descriptor.item === ItemKey.MessageFieldValue
  ? "\\S+"
  : descriptor.phrase
      .replace(/\?/g, "\\?") <- Good
      .replace(/\./g, "\\.") <- Good
      .replace(/\//g, "\\/") <- Good
      .replace(/\\/g, "\\\") <- ** No Good
      .replace(/\(/g, "\\(") <- Good
      .replace(/\)/g, "\\)") <- Good
      .toLowerCase()
      .split(/\s/)
      .join("\\s");
 const pattern = new RegExp(`^${phrasePattern}(?=\\s|$)`);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because \" is for saying to JS that you are using " as a character and not as the end of a string
So you need to add a 4th \ to say "I want to use \ as a character and not as an escape"

Comment: Thanks. @aime-aine that worked..  But stupidly noticed the other replacement with fowrad slash doesn't work.. Doesnt error but doesn't seem to replace properly either.  Do I need to escape the forward slash version?

 '   .replace(/\//g, "\\/")

Comment: remember that \ is for escaping characters so everytime you add a \ as a character you need to add a \ next to it to say "I want to use it as a character" i.e your first line should look like
 .replace(/\?/g, "\\\\?")
Maybe change your code editor parameters to have regex enhancement